# Trying to change array value inside object property

Tags: javascript

Im doing a project where i need to select a random element inside an array which is stored inside an objects property, then change it to something else with a method. here is the step of the project:

> .mutate() is responsible for randomly selecting a base in the object’s
>   dna property and changing the current base to a different base. Then
>   .mutate() will return the object’s dna.
>
> For example, if the randomly selected base is the 1st base and it is
>   'A', the base must be changed to 'T', 'C', or 'G'. But it cannot be
>   'A' again.

when i attempt this my output always ends up like this:
the first array is the original array
[ 'C', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'G' ]
[ 'C',
  'T',
  'A',
  'A',
  'G',
  'A',
  'G',
  'G',
  'C',
  'G',
  'T',
  'A',
  'A',
  'T',
  'G',
  NaN: 'G' ]

```
   // Returns a random DNA base
const returnRandBase = () => {
  const dnaBases = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']
  return dnaBases[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)] 
}

// Returns a random single stand of DNA containing 15 bases
const mockUpStrand = () => {
  const newStrand = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    newStrand.push(returnRandBase())
  }
  return newStrand
}

const pAequorFactory= (num, strand) =>{
  return {
    specimenNum: num,
    dna: strand,
    mutate(){
      const randomI = Math.floor(Math.random * this.dna.length);
      let dnaBase = this.dna[randomI];
      const randomBase = returnRandBase()
      if(dnaBase !== randomBase){
        this.dna[randomI] = randomBase
      } else {
        this.mutate()
      }
      return this.dna
    }
  }
}

const specimen1 = pAequorFactory(1,[ 'C', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'G' ]);

console.log(specimen1.dna)
console.log(specimen1.mutate())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
const randomI = Math.floor(Math.random * this.dna.length);
```

to

```
const randomI = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.dna.length);
```

`.random()` is a method, you need `()` to call it.
Currently `Math.random` evaluates to `NaN` therefore `randomI` is `NaN` too and your code 'breaks'